# Search Form in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-2.0

I have an admin site in ASP.NET 2.0 which I want to convert to ASP.NET MVC. I created a DB assembly in C#/LINQ which will get me all the DB information. Now getting to the UI, my current site allows users to specify multiple criteria, like city, order date, ship date, product name, product id, sku, upc, etc.

As ASP.NET MVC is a different beast, how do I go about creating this sort of UI? Are there code samples that I could learn from?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the [NerdDinner](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/04/28/free-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-tutorial-now-in-html.aspx) tutorial, as your question is a pretty general one about forms in MVC, and that's as good as place to start as any.